# macOS as host for LFS - good idea or not?

Tags: lfs

So I have a `hackintosh` with `macOS Catalina` and a second SSD I'd like to try build `LFS` onto.

Should I even try following the book from `macOS` as a `host` or I'll be better off using `some live-usb distro`; and if latter, which one should I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux From Scratch makes use of a pretty broad set of console tools on the host to do its work.  The problem is MacOS console tools are BSD versions which generally lack many of the GNU extensions that are completely standard on Linux.  It might be possible, but it's probably not easy, and almost certainly requires enough knowledge of both systems to figure out how to rework or replace instructions.  A live distro instead is going to be lower friction, at least until you need gigabytes and gigabytes of space to compile a kernel.

Comment: Will Ubuntu on USB do as a host system or should I get something else?

Comment: It should work.  Almost any live distro should work.  I know there's a way to get an Ubuntu live USB with persistent changes so you might want to pursue that for convenience.